# Loop error in EJS not working with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to loop in an EJS file but keep getting a weird mistake. First, my data looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Marina Silva",
    "info": [{
            "periodBegins": "Sun Apr 14 23:48:36 +0000 2011",
            "periodFinishes": "Sun Apr 7 23:48:36 +0000 2011",
            "words": [{"text": "evangelico", "size":32}, 
                      {"text": "PT", "size": 12},
                      {"text": "Rede Solidariedade", "size": 34},
                      {"text": "catolico", "size": 23}]
            },
            {
            "periodBegins": "Sun Apr 7 23:48:36 +0000 2011",
            "periodFinishes": "Sun Apr 1 23:48:36 +0000 2011",
            "words": [{"text": "Bolsonaro", "size":32}, 
                      {"text": "esperanças", "size": 12},
                      {"text": "deserto", "size": 34},
                      {"text": "oasis", "size": 23}]
            }
        ]
}
```

and from the controller file, I'm returning it as is, without calling JSON.stringify() on it. 
On my view file, I'm able to print it to the screen using

```
<%= politician %>
```

but when I try to access the 'name' property using

```
<table>
  <% for(var i=0; i < politician.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= politician.length %></td>
        <td><%= politician[i].name %></td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

I'm 1 - not able to get the name and 2 - it says that my object has a size of 563, which is the size of the string containing the data. However, it doesn't make sense to me since I think it should be treated as a JSON object and not a string. 
I tried using JSON.parse() in the data object, but all I get in the view is [object Object]. How can I loop through my JSON data and show it in a table?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Your given json is not simple json object but this is [json array object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) means "multi objects within single array"**

> Here i just parse name value from JSON Array object to show you how
>   can you parse it to get required value

```js
var jsondata = '{"name":"Marina Silva","info":[{"periodBegins":"Sun Apr 14 23:48:36 +0000 2011","periodFinishes":"Sun Apr 7 23:48:36 +0000 2011","words":[{"text":"evangelico","size":32},{"text":"PT","size":12},{"text":"Rede Solidariedade","size":34},{"text":"catolico","size":23}]},{"periodBegins":"Sun Apr 7 23:48:36 +0000 2011","periodFinishes":"Sun Apr 1 23:48:36 +0000 2011","words":[{"text":"Bolsonaro","size":32},{"text":"esperanças","size":12},{"text":"deserto","size":34},{"text":"oasis","size":23}]}]}';

var parseVal = JSON.parse(jsondata);
console.log(parseVal.name)
```

Comment: I know that but EJS doesn't let me iterate through the object, so returning JSON.parse(jsondata) doesn't work in the front end